# How to give a three a 3D effect to my cube?

Tags: javascript, three.js

How to add a 3D light effect like on this image to my cube below ?
[image]

If I replace `BasicMaterial` by `MeshPhongMaterial` or other material, I get a black cube.

```js
var camera = null;
var scene = null;
var renderer = null;
var cube = null;
var angle = null;

init();
renderer.render(scene, camera);

function init() {

 camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(1, 1);
 camera.position.z = 200;
    camera.position.set(50, -300, 100);
    camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

 // Make a scene
 scene = new THREE.Scene();

 clock = new THREE.Clock();

 //
 renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true,
  alpha: true
 });
 let container = document.getElementById('container');
 renderer.setSize(container.offsetWidth, container.offsetHeight);
 container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

 let cube2 = createCube();
 cube2.name = "cube2";
 //       cube2.position = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0)
 scene.add(cube2);

}

function createCube() {

 // GEOMETRY

 // 1. Start with empty geometry
 let geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

 // 2. Add vertices to geometry
 geometry.vertices.push(
  // verts [0-3] are in in +z
  new THREE.Vector3(-1, 1, 1),
  new THREE.Vector3(-1, -1, 1),
  new THREE.Vector3(1, -1, 1),
  new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1),
  // verts [4-7] in -z
  new THREE.Vector3(-1, 1, -1),
  new THREE.Vector3(-1, -1, -1),
  new THREE.Vector3(1, -1, -1),
  new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, -1),
 );

 // 3. Connect vertices in desired order to make faces
 let b = 0x1db0ec;
 let y = 0xffef3a;
 let r = 0xea353d;
 let w = 0x00ff00;

 // Set half faces
 geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2)); // blue
 geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 2, 3)); // yellow
 geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(5, 4, 6)); // white
 geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(6, 4, 7)); // red

 // Set whole faces
 geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(1, 0, 5)); // blue
 geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(5, 0, 4));
 geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(1, 5, 2)); // white
 geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(5, 6, 2));
 geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(2, 6, 3)); // red
 geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(3, 6, 7));
 geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 3, 4)); // yellow
 geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(3, 7, 4));

 // Set faces colors
 geometry.faces[0].color.setHex(b); // Half face
 geometry.faces[1].color.setHex(y);
 geometry.faces[2].color.setHex(w);
 geometry.faces[3].color.setHex(r);
 geometry.faces[4].color.setHex(b); // Whole face
 geometry.faces[5].color.setHex(b);
 geometry.faces[6].color.setHex(w);
 geometry.faces[7].color.setHex(w);
 geometry.faces[8].color.setHex(r);
 geometry.faces[9].color.setHex(r);
 geometry.faces[10].color.setHex(y);
 geometry.faces[11].color.setHex(y);

 // MATERIAL

 // Make a material
 let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  // color: 0x00FF00,
  vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors,
  wireframe: false,
 });

 // MESH

 let cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
 return cube;
}
```

```css
#container {
      width: 20em;
      height: 20em;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>

        <div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a light source to your scene.
[`MeshPhongMaterial`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/MeshPhongMaterial) uses a non-physically based Blinn-Phong model for calculating reflectance.
If there is no light source, then no light is reflected and the object appears all black.

e.g. [`AmbientLight`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/lights/AmbientLight) and [`DirectionalLight`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/lights/DirectionalLight):

```js
let ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
scene.add(ambientLight);

let directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
directionalLight.position.set(1,1,1);
scene.add(directionalLight);
```

Furthermore to compute the reflection of the light normal vectors are required.
e.g. Use [`.computeFaceNormals()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Geometry) to compute the normal vectors of the faces:

```js
let material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors,
    wireframe: false});

geometry.computeFaceNormals();
let cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
```

See the example:

```js
var camera = null;
var scene = null;
var renderer = null;
var cube = null;
var angle = null;

init();
renderer.render(scene, camera);

function init() {

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(1, 1);
  camera.position.z = 200;
  camera.position.set(50, -300, 100);
  camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

  // Make a scene
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  let ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
  scene.add(ambientLight);

  let directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
  directionalLight.position.set(2,-3,1);
  scene.add(directionalLight);

  clock = new THREE.Clock();

  //
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true,
  alpha: true
  });
  let container = document.getElementById('container');
  renderer.setSize(container.offsetWidth, container.offsetHeight);
  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  let cube2 = createCube();
  cube2.name = "cube2";
  //       cube2.position = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0)
  scene.add(cube2);
}

function createCube() {

  // GEOMETRY

  // 1. Start with empty geometry
  let geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

  // 2. Add vertices to geometry
  geometry.vertices.push(
  // verts [0-3] are in in +z
  new THREE.Vector3(-1, 1, 1),
  new THREE.Vector3(-1, -1, 1),
  new THREE.Vector3(1, -1, 1),
  new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1),
  // verts [4-7] in -z
  new THREE.Vector3(-1, 1, -1),
  new THREE.Vector3(-1, -1, -1),
  new THREE.Vector3(1, -1, -1),
  new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, -1),
  );

  // 3. Connect vertices in desired order to make faces
  let b = 0x1db0ec;
  let y = 0xffef3a;
  let r = 0xea353d;
  let w = 0x00ff00;

  // Set half faces
  geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2)); // blue
  geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 2, 3)); // yellow
  geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(5, 4, 6)); // white
  geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(6, 4, 7)); // red

  // Set whole faces
  geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(1, 0, 5)); // blue
  geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(5, 0, 4));
  geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(1, 5, 2)); // white
  geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(5, 6, 2));
  geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(2, 6, 3)); // red
  geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(3, 6, 7));
  geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 3, 4)); // yellow
  geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(3, 7, 4));

  // Set faces colors
  geometry.faces[0].color.setHex(b); // Half face
  geometry.faces[1].color.setHex(y);
  geometry.faces[2].color.setHex(w);
  geometry.faces[3].color.setHex(r);
  geometry.faces[4].color.setHex(b); // Whole face
  geometry.faces[5].color.setHex(b);
  geometry.faces[6].color.setHex(w);
  geometry.faces[7].color.setHex(w);
  geometry.faces[8].color.setHex(r);
  geometry.faces[9].color.setHex(r);
  geometry.faces[10].color.setHex(y);
  geometry.faces[11].color.setHex(y);

  // MATERIAL

  // Make a material
  let material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors,
    wireframe: false});

  // MESH

  geometry.computeFaceNormals()
  let cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  return cube;
}
```

```css
#container {width: 20em; height: 20em;}
```

```html
<!--script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but the colors are lost in this example, how can it be preserved ?

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot !

Comment: You might want to point that three.js link to a versioned cdn so it doesn't break tomorrow.